# Based on inputs in one textbox, query a MySQL database and update another textbox

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Basically, I've got a MySQL table with an id (primary key) and name. When the user enters a number into the "ID" textbox on the webform, I want to update another text box with the name based on the id that was entered. What's the best way to do this?

What I'm currently doing feels very stupid, but it works. When my page loads, I pull the id and name into a `DataTable` object. Then when the textbox changes (`TextChanged event`), I post back to the server and then search through my datatable and change the value of the name textbox.

It works, but it's kind of slow because of the post back. I got a feeling this is possible with javascript to make the form feel much more responsive? But I'm not even sure what to google. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript for this. There's no need to post back to the server.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('input[name="txtid"]').on('change keyup',function()
        {
            $('input[name="txtnotifications"]').val
            (
                $('input[name="txtid"]').val()
            );
        });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="/">
  <input name="txtid" type="text" />
  <br />
  <input name="txtnotifications" type="text" />
</form>
```

Also, it seems curious that the user is entering the id. That's usually a database managed field and the user is not able to create/update it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use that. How do I link my MySQL data to the javascript code?

Anyway I should be more specific. This is part of a college project where I'm supposed to create a user interface for an administrator to insert a "booking" record for a hotel management system. So the id is the hotel id, and I want to display what name the admin is inserting based on the id he keyed into the textbox

Comment: Hmmm - you might look at something like this. 

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

You'll be queryinging the database based on the input of the text field and returning matches as the user types. 

And here's a walkthrough.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_autocomplete_simple.ashx

Answer (score 0):

If the hotel table is small, pull out all the records and render as javascript array object.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="txtID" type="text" runat="server" />
<input id="txtName" type="text" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= txtID.ClientID%>').on('change keyup', function () {
            var result = $.grep(hotels, function (e) { return e.id == $('#<%= txtID.ClientID%>').val(); });
            var output;

            if (result.length == 0) {
                // not found
                output = 'Hotel not found!!!';
            } else if (result.length == 1) {
                // access the foo property using result[0].foo
                output = result[0].name;
            } else {
                // multiple items found
                output = 'Multiple hotels found!!!';
            }

            $('#<%= txtName.ClientID%>').val(output);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In code behind, what you need to do is render the records as serialized JSON string:

```
Private Sub rendertHotelList()
    Dim dt As DataTable = ... ' read hotel data from db into datatable

    Dim hotels = From row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
                 Select id = CStr(row!EmployeeID), name = row!LastName

    Dim jss As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim s As String = jss.Serialize(hotels)

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), "hotel_array", "var hotels = " & s, True)

End Sub
```

This way, no postback to the server needed when user type in the id value.

However, if the table contains large number of records and you need to keep the page size as small as possible, use ajax request to retrieve the name.